# Determine the primes p for which $6\in Q_p$(where $Q_p$ denotes quadratic residue)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Background This is from Jones Elementary Number theory problem 7.12. I only want the case where $6\in Q_p$ to be worked although the original problem asks for -3,5,6,7,10,169.
Using Legendre's notation and the Quadratic reciprocity law I get:
\begin{align}
\textrm{If }P \equiv & 1 \mod 4&\\
\left(\frac{2}{p}\right)\left(\frac{3}{p}\right) &=\\
\left(\frac{p}{2}\right)\left(\frac{p}{3}\right) &\implies p \equiv  1 \mod 2 \\
&\quad \quad \;\; p \equiv  1 \mod 3 \\
\hline
Thus&\implies p\equiv 1 \mod 6\\
\end{align}

$$
\left.
\begin{array}{l}
p\equiv 1 \mod 4\\
p \equiv 1 \mod 6
\end{array}
\right\}\bbox[5px,border:1px solid red]{p \equiv 1,13 \mod 24}
$$

---

\begin{align}
\textrm{If }P \equiv & 3 \mod 4&\\
\left(\frac{2}{p}\right)\left(\frac{3}{p}\right) &=\\
\left(\frac{p}{2}\right)\left(-\frac{p}{3}\right) &\implies p \equiv  1 \mod 2 \\
&\quad \quad \;\; p \equiv  2 \mod 3 \\
\hline
Thus&\implies p\equiv 5 \mod 6\\
\end{align}

$$
\left.
\begin{array}{l}
p\equiv 3 \mod 4\\
p \equiv 5 \mod 6
\end{array}
\right\}\bbox[5px,border:1px solid red]{p \equiv 11,23 \mod 24}
$$

The text solution is $p \equiv \pm1 \text{ or } \pm 5 \mod 24$. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Take $p=5$, then you will see what you did wrong. In fact, $6\equiv 1^2 \bmod 5$, so $6\in Q_5$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Quadratic Reciprocity law only applies to odd primes $p,q$, and $2$ is not an odd prime. In fact we have
$$\left(\frac{2}{p}\right)=(-1)^{(p^2-1)/8}$$
which does not just depend on the value of $p$ mod $4$. So you will have to split the problem up into more cases.

Comment: I'm still doing something wrong. For the case where $p \equiv 7 \mod 8$, $p \equiv 1 \mod 4$, $p \equiv 1 \mod 3$, to make $\left(\frac{2}{p}\right)\left(\frac{p}{3}\right)$ positive there is no solution to the Chinese Remainder theorem because $GCD(8,4) \not \mid 7-1$.

Comment: $\left(\frac{2}{p}\right)\left(\frac{p}{3}\right)$ is indeed positive, but you want $\left(\frac{2}{p}\right)\left(\frac{3}{p}\right)$, which is negative.

Comment: I was trying to work the case where $p \equiv 1 \mod 4$ first, where $\left(\frac{3}{p}\right)\equiv\left(\frac{p}{3}\right)$

Comment: So then why did you pick $p\equiv7$ mod $8$?

Comment: Aha!. Things get a little complicated when you have to create the congruences yourself

Comment: I see that I was wrong to say that $\left(\frac{2}{p}\right)\left(\frac{p}{3}\right)$ is positive -- it depends on $p$ mod $3$. (I mistakenly assumed your $p$ was _equal_ to $7$.) But I think you are on the right track now?

Comment: Yes, I'll see if that fixed it later today. You can't blame yourself for inconsistent congruences...